# Extra BR tag appears between P tags on Facebook fan page notes

Tags: html, facebook, rss

We have a Facebook page that imports notes from our RSS feed. Content from our feed is like

```
<p>Foo bar.</p>
<p>Bar foo.</p>
```

At our Facebook page, when the note is imported, content is like

```
<p>Foo bar.</p><br /><p>Bar foo.</p>
```

Apparently the \n in the original content is replaced with a br tag.

As a result, this FB note is a burden to read.

I haven't yet tried removing the \n between paragraphs in original content. I was hoping this issue could be fixed without such artificial maneuvers.

Our feed goes through Feedburner. Not sure if that's related.

Any ideas how to get rid of this extra line break?

Comment: Is it related with your browser ou reader ?

Comment: Thanks, but there's an extra br tag in source code = not browser related.

Answer (score 0):

Set the open graph og:title and og:description meta tags as described here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/